# Should duplicate answers be posted, just to include screen shots?

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates, images

I stumbled upon [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/156626/change-properties-privilege-level-command-prompt-in-windows-7) which has an answer posted (and edited) months ago. Just today, a new answer was posted with the exact same steps as the old answer, but including screen shots of the process.

I can understand there would be a few exceptions to this rule, primarily when the process outlined is very hard to follow and the screen shots bring a lot of clarification, but in this case, and in a few others I've seen, the screen shots don't bring much to the table, and the steps outlined are exact dupes of another answer. What's the etiquette for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I normally edit someone else's answer to add pictures if I think it could use them.

Now I know not everyone is capable of doing so, but as long as it's a minor change I would just leave a comment with a link to the image I think they should add.

If the question is very old you do have the risk that the user isn't very active anymore. In case you feel very strong about providing the image, then it's probably OK to add your own.

But **I prefer adding the image to the post that was earlier.**

Answer (score 2):

That's tricky because you ideally want each person to get credit, but you also want a merged best answer.

In this *specific* case it's only one screenshot, not an entire series of 6 screenshots, so **I am OK with it**.

It's too small of a post for this to really be a problem, I don't think a single screenshot is harming the other post; if you want the text, read answer #2, if you want a screenshot, read answer #1.